# java- OutOfMemoryError with -Xms1000M -Xmx4000M -mx1000m

Tags: java

Using: -Xms1000M -Xmx4000M -mx1000m
I still get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

If I try to increase any of these numbers, I get the following JVM error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

How can I solve this OutOfMemoryError problem?
(even if I need to cache memory on disk)

Comment: What are you doing to cause the OoM error?

Comment: You might have a memory leak somewhere. Use a profiler to find out for sure.

Comment: i am just using the jai-imageio library to read a 100Mb JPEG2000 file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much memory does your system have? Are you running windows? You can't create much more than 1G heap with a 32bit windows JVM. If your Xms setting is greater than this limit the JVM will fail to initialize.

JPEG images are compressed. A 100M JPEG is pretty large and will be a lot larger once decompressed by the image io lib. OOM with 1G heap is quite conceivable.

Barry

Comment: yes, it is a 32bit windows; is there a way to tell JVM to use a file for the heap memory, instead of ram memory (to be able to increase the heap space, even in a 32bit windows)?

Comment: You can swap space but the size of the heap on a 32-bit system is limited to about 1.2 to 1.5 GB. The most you can access on a 32-bit system in theory is 4 GB (i.e. 2^32) and the limit for Windows is 3.5 GB. The continuous memory you can get is what limits the heap size.  BTW: If you exceed your physical memory, your program will slow down by a factor of 10 or more.