# java- use a file for java heap space bigger than 1Gb in a 32bit windows

Tags: java

Using: -Xms1000M -Xmx4000M -mx1000m I still get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I am using the jai-imageio library to read a 100Mb JPEG2000 file, and it may need more than 1Gb heap space once decompressed by the imageio lib.
I am using a 32bit windows JVM, so I can't create more than 1G heap space.

See this post: [java- OutOfMemoryError with -Xms1000M -Xmx4000M -mx1000m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264123/java-outofmemoryerror-with-xms1000m-xmx4000m-mx1000m/10264438#10264438)

So, is there a way to tell JVM to use a file for the heap memory, instead of ram memory (to be able to have a heap space bigger than 1Gb, even in a 32bit windows)?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Why don't you believe what you've already read?

Comment: Time to switch to 64bit technology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java- OutOfMemoryError with -Xms1000M -Xmx4000M -mx1000m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264123/java-outofmemoryerror-with-xms1000m-xmx4000m-mx1000m)

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of the operating system (and the number of bits you have in your addresses). You need to use a 64-bit OS and a 64-bit JVM.

When you add to the swap space you are allowing the JVM to use this file as swap space. Note: do so can decrease your performance by 10x or more.

You should be able to get a heap of between 1.2 GB and 1.5 GB on 32-bit windows.

A  similar question was asked here. [How much -XX:MaxPermSize size i can mention for 4GB and 8GB Ram and calculation for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266404/how-much-xxmaxpermsize-size-i-can-mention-for-4gb-and-8gb-ram-and-calculation)